# CHS to LBA on Micro SD Cards

Tags: filesystems

The formula for translating CHS to LBA and back, but I have problem getting it to work with micro sd cards. As you can see here

```
LBA = ((cylinder * heads_per_cylinder + heads) * sectors_per_track) + sector - 1
```

The formula needs to know about **heads_per_cylinder** and **sectors_per_track**, but as far as I know micro sd cards doesn't have any geometry? Is there some magic numbers I should use or?

The reason for this is that I play around with MBR partitionning.

Answer (score 0):

Try heads_per_cylinder = 4 and sectors_per_track = 32